# chrome onAuthRequired not firing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, authentication

I'm trying to login automatically to a website in a chrome extension.

I'm using the latest version of Chrome.
I tried several syntaxes and samples to fire OnAuthRequired in vain.

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
function(details, callback) {   
console.log("onAuthRequired!", details, callbackFn);  
callback({authCredentials: {username: "test", password: "test"}});    
}, 
{urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
["asyncBlocking"]
);
```

I tried the keyword "blocking" instead of "asyncBlocking" as well.

also tried to create a function:

```
function sendCredentials(status)
{   
    console.log(status);
    return {username: "bob", password: "test"}; 
}
```

onAuthRequired just never fires.

My manifest contains:

```
"permissions": [ "contextMenus", "tabs", "https://*/*", "http://*/*", "clipboardWrite", "clipboardRead", "storage", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking" ],
```

For the full story, using onBeforeRequest, I'm redirecting one specific URL to another url. And the redirected url requires authentication.

```
function onHookBeforeRequest(details)
{   
    return { redirectUrl: myServer};
}
```

I tried to inject directly the authorization header and I didn't find a way to do it.
I then tried to hook the onAuthRequired and I'm also stuck here.
When the redirected url requires authentication, it returns a 401 with a WWW-Authenticate header.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to re-authenticate by Quitting Google Chrome and restarting it.

Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit) on OSX 10.9.5